# how to check for third variable (ans) in adder game?

Tags: java, variables, object, methods

Ok so this has been picking my brain for a whole 48 hours :(

The adding game is suppose to give 2 random numbers (adding them), track the amount of tries it takes to answer correctly and give points based on the amount of tries up to 4, at 4 tries the number resets you get zero points and it tells you the answer then generates 2 more numbers. At any point if your guess includes 99 the game ends. Without using a `for` or `do while` including a `break;`.

How do i get it to stop when `ans == 99`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class AdderGame {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int ans = 0;
        int tries;
        int score = 0;

        Player one = new Player (0 , 0);
        while (ans != 99) {
            tries = one.getTry();
            ans = one.getAns();

            switch (tries) {
            case 1: score += 5; break;
            case 2: score +=3; break;
            case 3: score += 1; break;
            case 4: score += 0;
            System.out.print("The right answer is "); break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Your Score is " + score);
    }
}


import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {
    int ran1, ran2;
    int tries = 1;
    int answer;
    int guess;

    public Player(int trys, int ans) {
        tries = trys;
        answer = ans;
    }

    public int getTry() m{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ran1 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
        ran2 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
        answer = ran1 + ran2;

        do {
            System.out.print(ran1 + " + " + ran2 + ": ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            if (guess == answer) {
                return (tries);
            } else {
                tries += 1;
            }
        } while (tries <= 4 && answer != guess || guess != 99);
        return (tries);
    }

    public int getAns() {
        return (answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if this seems trivial but im just getting the hang of object orientated programming and there is no teacher this example came from a book so im not sure where else to go for guidance thanks

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question? What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what output do you get and how does it differ from what you want? Please provide more details and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: no no errors, it does not stop though when i enter 99 or if i get it wrong more than four times.

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger to step through your code and view the values of the variables. In particular, pay close attention to the condition of your do...while loop. Getting the logic correct with && and || is tricky, even for experienced programmers.

Comment: thank you i appreciate the help. Any suggestion on my use of objects?, the book "suggests" i use two more classes with objects in addition to the main one but i dont feel the need but then again im not a good programmer

Comment: I suggest that you study the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In short, each method should do one thing well. Same goes for each class. In this particular case, one thing I notice is that `getTry()` seems to be doing too much in a single method.

Comment: One other small detail: `tries` is an internal variable that is used by the `Player` class. The `main()` method doesn't need to know that it even exists. This means that you don't need to have a constructor parameter to initialize it. Better yet, you can declare it as a local variable in the `getTry()` method.

Comment: interesting thank you for your suggestions, like i said im going off a book so its not exactly good for questions outside its context. much appreciated @Code-Guru!

Comment: no problem. Often branching out on your own is a great way to learn.

Comment: yes unfortunately even though i am on a computer science track, for the most part of the next 3 years (im a sophomore) im only taking prerequisites for the university and my specific school so experience in programming is up to me ); ..GUI next week !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several reasons your program is incorrect.

1. You are using the "answer" to stop, and not the guess.  You should be checking to make sure the "guess" is not 99.
2. In your Player `while loop` you need to change that logic to make it so that it stops also when the guess is 99. Right now you are using the logical **or** but you need to change that to **and**.

Revised code:

```
public class AdderGame {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int ans = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        int tries;
        int score = 0;

        Player one = new Player (0 , 0);
        while (guess != 99) {
            tries = one.getTry();
            ans = one.getAns();
            guess = one.getGuess(); // notice I'm getting the guess
            switch (tries) {
            case 1: score += 5; break;
            case 2: score += 3; break;
            case 3: score += 1; break;
            case 4: score += 0;
            System.out.print("The right answer is "); break;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Your Score is " + score);
    }
}

// Methods from inside of your Player class
public int getTry(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ran1 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    ran2 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    answer = ran1 + ran2;

    do {
        System.out.print(ran1 + " + " + ran2 + ": ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == answer) {
            return (tries);
        } else {
            tries += 1;
        }
    // Notice that it's now `&& guess != 99` instead of `||`
    } while (tries <= 4 && answer != guess && guess != 99);
    return (tries);
}
// new getter for getting the guess
public int getGuess(){
    return guess;
}
```

Comment: ahh i see you are very right sir. like i said not a very good programmer haha but getting there if slowly. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that you just want to close the program when they have 999.

```
if (Integer.toString(guess).contains('999')) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/** by the way if anyone is actually looking at more than just my question regarding the context of the program, i did make a mistake in the do while method of getTry()...it will not add up the tries and stop at four and it will give you 5 points just for entering 99 in the first problem (silly me)  */

```
public int getTry() m{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ran1 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    ran2 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    answer = ran1 + ran2;

    do {
        System.out.print(ran1 + " + " + ran2 + ": ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == answer) {
            return (tries);
        } else {
            tries += 1;
        }
    } while (tries <= 4 && answer != guess || guess != 99);
    return (tries);
} // old version

 public int getTry(){
    int tries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ran1 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    ran2 = (int) (19 * Math.random());
    answer = ran1 + ran2;

    do {
        System.out.print(ran1 + " + " + ran2 + ": ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
       if (guess == 99){
           return tries;
       } else if (guess != answer && tries == 4) {
           System.out.println("Wrong 4x, correct answer is: " + answer);
       }
        else {
           tries += 1;
           System.out.println(tries);
       }
    } while (tries <= 3 && guess != answer && guess != 99);
    return (tries);
} // new and improved do while - hope it finds use to someone
```